# ZK : Creatin listbox from arrayList

Tags: java, listbox, arraylist, zk

I am trying to make a listbox from my two array. One of them has column names and the other list has inside two list that contains values.

I can set headers from string , but I cant separate values to list cells. It shows two list item but only one list cell. Like

```
   HEADER 1 |  HEADER 2 | HEADER 3 
   [1, 2, 0] 
   [1, 7, 0]
```

I should separate them . Here my .zul code

```
<listbox id="listModel"
        mold="paging" pageSize="20" rows="20" selectedItem="@{mainCtrl.selected}">
    <listhead forward="onDoubleClick=onRemoveFromHeader()">
            <listheader label="${each}"
                        forEach="${comboModelColumns}" />
            </listhead>

        <listitem
                label="${each}"
                forEach="${listValues}">
            </listitem>
        </listbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me

```
<listitem
                                        forEach="${listValues}">
                                        <listcell
                                            forEach="${listValues[forEachStatus.index]}"
                                            label="${each}" />
                                    </listitem>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use the listitem renderer to render the multiple cell, please refer to [this guide](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Essentials/Displaying_information_using_the_Listbox/Using_a_ListModel_and_ListitemRenderer).

Or you can use this way but not good for the nested forEach.

```
<listitem forEach="${firstLoop}">
     <listcell forEach="${secondLoop}" .../>
</listitem>
```

Comment: for second loop I hade List that contains lists. forEachStatus.index helped me.